# I want to get all nextPageTokens in python youtube data api

Tags: python, youtube, logic

I'm trying to get `nextPageToken` in the youtube data api
below is my code, I want to get all `nextpageToken`s.
In the loop, I want to reassign `nextPageToken`

```
def get_next_videos():                                                                                                                                        
  while True:                                                                                                                                                 
    r = requests.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=50&channelId="+CHANNELID+"&order=date&key="+DEVELOPER_KEY)         
    json_data = r.json()                                                                                                                                      
    nextPageToken = json_data.get("nextPageToken")                                                                                                            

    second_r = requests.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=50&channelId="+CHANNELID+"&order=date&key="+DEVELOPER_KEY+"\
&pageToken="+nextPageToken)                                                                                                                                   
    json_data = second_r.json()                                                                                                                               
    nextPageToken = json_data.get("nextPageToken")                                                                                                            

    third_r = requests.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=50&channelId="+CHANNELID+"&order=date&key="+DEVELOPER_KEY+"&\
pageToken="+nextPageToken)                                                                                                                                    
    json_data = third_r.json()                                                                                                                                
    nextPageToken = json_data.get("nextPageToken")                                                                                                            

    fourth_r = requests.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=50&channelId="+CHANNELID+"&order=date&key="+DEVELOPER_KEY+"\
&pageToken="+nextPageToken)                                                                                                                                   
    json_data = third_r.json()                                                                                                                                
    nextPageToken = json_data.get("nextPageToken")
```

Answer (score 8):

Assuming that `nextPageToken` won't be returned when you're at the last page, then you could just do:

```
# First request
r = requests.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=50&channelId="+CHANNELID+"&order=date&key="+DEVELOPER_KEY)
json_data = r.json()                                                                                                
nextPageToken = json_data.get("nextPageToken")

# Retrieve all the rest of the pages
while nextPageToken:
    r = requests.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=50&channelId="+CHANNELID+"&order=date&key="+DEVELOPER_KEY+"&pageToken="+nextPageToken)
    json_data = r.json()
    nextPageToken = json_data.get("nextPageToken")
```

Of course, inside the loop, you probably also want to be collecting the data that you're retrieving in some appropriate data structure (list, dictionary, etc.).